# Can I give access to database without access to cpanel

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel, mysql-workbench

I'm going to give a freelancer access to the database. The idea was to give him the access with SSH (MySQL Workbench). But it came out that to do so, I would need to give him the password to my cpanel as well. Is there any other way, to give a database access without giving the access to the cpanel?

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download your database locally and then you can give him access/hand him over the database for changing and then import it back to your webhost or I don't know if you can use PHPmyAdmin?

Comment: Thanks, I did that and gave him also access via MySQL `Workbench`!